# ios volume manipulation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio

The client wants a fade in effect on sound when user swipes onto the next page. I know you can use setTimeout and volume to achieve the same but IOS doesn't allow JavaScript to change volume, it's only in control of the user (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW10). 
The below code works on desktop but not in IOS. Is there any other approach I can use?

```
function fadeVolume(volume, callback)
{
    var factor  = 0.1,
        speed   = 100;
    if (volume > factor)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            fadeVolume((document.getElementById('coverAudio').volume -= factor), callback);         
        }, speed);
    } else {
        console.log('failed');
    }
}
fadeVolume(document.getElementById('coverAudio').volume, function(){
    console.log('fade complete');
});
```